# How do I create HELP command for custom BAT files?

Tags: batch-file

I have written small script for converting text to `uppercase` as shown below and saved this file as `.BAT` extension

```
`converttoupper.bat`
```

I want user to try "help" command, so that they get the help on syntax for using the commands as shown below

```
help converttoupper
```

something like this

```
# help converttoupper
For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name
CONVERTTOUPPER This converts the text to upper case
```

**Update**

I am fine even if I get something as shown below. I do not want to overwrite any windows command.

```
helpme converttoupper

  or

  helpme connectvpn
```

I have many BAT files, and wish to display respective helps when each executed.

[image]

Comment: You already know that arguments are stored in `%1`/`%2`/etc. and you know what `if` statements are. What bit are you stuck on? Those two things should be all you need to know for this.

Comment: `help` is a Windows command ('C:\Windows\System32\help.exe`). You'd have to hack this program to include the help for your batch file. Besides that Windows has a safeguard to protect it from changed executables, you'd have to do that on every computer that is meant to run your batchfile. I'm sure that's not the way you want to go. Use the standard way instead: `converttoupper.bat /?` (you already demonstrated that you know how to handle parameters, so this should be trivial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "fake" function. Let's call this `define.cmd` and place it in `%systemroot%\system32`

We add the code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=? " %%i in ('type "%~1" ^|findstr ":?"') do echo %%j
```

Then in all your batch files you want people to read the help for, add the help lines by starting them off with a `:?` using your `convertoupper.cmd` file as example:

```
@echo off & set upper=
if "%~1" == "" echo incorrect usage & call define.cmd "%0"
if "%~1" == "/?" call define.cmd "%0"

for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%I in ('tree "\%~1"') do if not defined upper set "upper=%%~I"
set "upper=%upper:~3%"
echo %upper%
goto :eof
:? # help converttoupper
:? "define %0" or "%0 /?" will display this help content
:? For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name
:? CONVERTTOUPPER This converts the text to upper case
```

Now you can run `define converttoupper` or `converttoupper /?`. If you run `converttoupper` without any arguments, it will also display the same help.

Comment: I am getting below error - incorrect usage
'define.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I do not want to touch system32.  I can use something "helpme" rather than "help" so that it wont conflict with windows.

Comment: Did you save it in `c:\windows\system32\` then closed `cmd` and reopened it?

Comment: I do not want to use c:\windows\system32` because whenever system formats I do not want to loose files.

Comment: Yes, save it as `helpme` instead. You can put it anywhere else if you want to not use System32, but then simply define that path in your `%path%`

Comment: Sounds good , let me try. However I have many such BAT files. How single "helpme" file will pick the help content of respective BAT functions??  Let me know if I need to improve the question.

Comment: it will, if you standardize your batch files with the `:?` and have `helpme` in the path.

Comment: And? Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: It works awesome, thanks. unfortunately question was tagged for close. :(

Comment: It's fine. Answer was posted before closure.

Comment: some of the BAT files (commands) does not require parameters.  so when I do not pass parameter it still shows "incorrect usage" .  how to improve this solution now?

Comment: on those, just remove the first line `if "%~1" == "" echo incorrect usage & call define.cmd "%0"`

Comment: Done. working.  :) hope someone "reopen" this question so that it helps community.

Comment: The community can still read it, they can just not post answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of safely handling arg capture and help enqueries.

After arguments are safely Captured, Findstr is used to test the content for valid help switches:

`Set Args | %SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /bli "Args=\/? Args=-? Args=Help?" > nul && (Rem commands)`

- `Set Args` : allows the argument string to be piped to findstr without any risk of failure due to poison characters.
- `/bli` : findstr sawitches : match literal string at beginning of line ignoring case.
- `"Args=\/? Args=-? Args=Help?"` : Space delimited list of strings to match; treated as match string a or b or c
- `> nul` : Suppress the output of any match
- `&&` : Conditional operator; 'On command success'

Note: Terminating each help switch with `?` allows use of substring modification to remove the leading switch and space and directly Call a label prefixed with the query keyword

```bat
@Echo off & SETLOCAL
=========================================================================
 Rem -- Arg capture method is a modified version of Dave Benhams method:
 Rem -- https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4288#p23980
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
 1>"%~f0:Params.dat" <"%~f0:Params.dat" (
  SETLOCAL DisableExtensions
  Set prompt=#
  Echo on
  For %%a in (%%a) do rem . %*.
  Echo off
  ENDLOCAL
  Set /p "Args="
  Set /p "Args="
  Set "Args=!Args:~7,-2!"
  @Rem duplicate Args for the purpose of counting doublequotes [destructive].
  Set "DQcount=!Args!"
 ) || (
  Echo(%~nx0 requires an NTFS drive system to function as intended.
  CMD /C Exit -1073741510
 ) || Goto:Eof

 If Not defined Args Goto:NoArgs
REM substitute doublequotes in Args clone 'DQcount'; count substring in string;
REM assess if count is even; If false "||": Remove doublequotes from string. If true "&&" and if entire
REM arg line is doublequoted, remove outer quotes.
 Set Div="is=#", "1/(is<<9)"
 Set "{DQ}=0"
 Set ^"DQcount=!DQcount:"={DQ}!"
 2> nul Set "null=%DQcount:{DQ}=" & Set /A {DQ}+=1& set "null=%"

 Set /A !Div:#={DQ} %% 2! 2> nul && Set ^"Args=!Args:"=!" || If [^%Args:~0,1%^%Args:~-1%] == [""] Set "Args=!Args:~1,-1!")

 For /f Delims^= %%G in ("!Args!")Do Endlocal & Set "Args=%%G" 2> nul
:NoArgs

=====================================================================

Rem help query assessment
 (
  Set Args | %SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /bli "Args=\/? Args=-? Args=Help?" > nul && (
   Rem Args value has leading /? -? or help?
   If not "%Args:*?=%"=="" (
    Rem Args value contains leading /? -? or help? with additional Parameter
    Call:%Args:*? =%_Syntax && Goto:Eof || (
     Rem quit after Call to Syntax info if valid Parameter; else notify invalid and show valid syntax queries.
     Echo(Invalid query: "%Args:*? =%" : Does not Match a valid Help Query:
    )
   )
   Rem show valid syntax queries.
   For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=:_" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /R "^:.*_Syntax" "%~f0"') Do Echo(%~nx0 /? %%G
   ENDLOCAL & Exit /b 0
  )
 ) 2> nul

 Set Args

 Goto:Eof

Rem Demo syntax labels

:Demo_Syntax
Echo %~0 help info
Exit /b 0


:Example_Syntax
Echo %~0 help info
Exit /b 0
```